# C++ QT QML : disabling a specific keyboard key on the whole program

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a C++ program which uses QML. Workplace wants me to prevent people from using alt + tab, alt + ctrl + del or alt + F4 on it in order to prevent the user from circumventing the standard program exit button and going back to desktop *(I might have to cancel more shortcuts than that but so far I'm focusing on these three)*.

The easiest way I could see myself implementing that is disabling some specific keyboard keys, such as the "alt" key which is pretty much used in all of the shortcuts listed above. But I couldn't find any way to intercept and block alt key presses for my whole program, though I did find something for intercepting the "ctrl" key :

```
class MyWindowsEventFilter : public QAbstractNativeEventFilter
{
    public:
        virtual bool nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
        {
            if (eventType == "windows_generic_MSG") 
            {   //This intercepts the control key, but what I actually want is intercepting the "alt key
                MSG* ev = static_cast<MSG *>(message);
                if (ev->message == WM_KEYDOWN && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)) {
                    qDebug() << "Captured CONTROL+" << ev->wParam;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
};
```

I wanted to see if I could repurpose that function to intercept the "alt" key instead, but I cannot seem to find any "VK" defines for this specific key. In addition to this, I can't seem to be able to use the "installEventFilter" function with this MyWindowsEventFilter class on my QGuiApplication object, because this function requires a QObject* object rather than something that extends from QAbstractNativeEventFilter.

Is there a way to prevent presses on the alt key for my whole program ?

Comment: Remind me not to buy any software from your company. I know you're not responsible for these requirements, but they are absurd.

Comment: Note users could easily kill your program with a simple restart (or other keybindings). You are probably in search of a [Kiosk](https://forum.qt.io/topic/30573/qt-kiosk-application/10) app.

Comment: It simply won't work this way. You have to restrict things in your hosting application/OS not from within your program.

Comment: In the Windows documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) the alt key is named VK_MENU. Not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard QT event filter and register it to the application. Than you can handle any key pressed **for your application**.

```
class KeyInterceptor: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    protected:
      bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
};

bool KeyInterceptor::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);

        if (keyEvent->modifiers() == Qt::ALT) {
            qDebug("press ALT...do something");
            return true;
        }
    }

    // normal handling
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

and in the main program:

```
app.installEventFilter(new KeyInterceptor());
```

But you **can not handle other key event handlers** (like the operating system) handling the ALT-TAB sequence anyway.